# Postfix mysql warning: /etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf: Permission denied

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, postfix

I am running postfix on an ubuntu 20.04 server. I am trying to fix some warnings in my /var/log/mail.err file I am getting the following:

```
Aug  9 09:34:45 mail postfix/proxymap[281260]: error: open /etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf: Permission denied
Aug  9 09:36:49 mail postfix/proxymap[282230]: error: open /etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf: Permission denied
Aug  9 09:36:49 mail postfix/proxymap[282230]: error: open /etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_maps.cf: Permission denied
Aug  9 09:36:49 mail postfix/proxymap[282230]: error: open /etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_catchall_maps.cf: Permission denied
Aug  9 09:36:49 mail postfix/proxymap[282230]: error: open /etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf: Permission denied
Aug  9 10:25:49 mail postfix/proxymap[304446]: error: open /etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf: Permission denied
Aug  9 10:27:49 mail postfix/proxymap[304446]: error: open /etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_maps.cf: Permission denied
Aug  9 10:27:49 mail postfix/proxymap[304446]: error: open /etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_catchall_maps.cf: Permission denied
Aug  9 10:27:49 mail postfix/proxymap[304446]: error: open /etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf: Permission denied
```

In my /var/log/mail.log file I am getting:

```
Aug  9 10:53:49 mail postfix/proxymap[304446]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf is unavailable. open /etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf: Permission denied
Aug  9 10:53:49 mail postfix/cleanup[306706]: warning: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf lookup error for "example@example.com"
Aug  9 10:53:49 mail postfix/cleanup[306706]: warning: 359E0123381: virtual_alias_maps map lookup problem for example@examplle.com -- message not accepted, try again later
Aug  9 10:53:49 mail postfix/pickup[282225]: 36D3B123381: uid=997 from=<netdata>
Aug  9 10:53:49 mail opendmarc[1127]: ignoring connection from localhost
Aug  9 10:53:49 mail postfix/cleanup[306428]: 36D3B123381: message-id=<20220809155349.36D3B123381@mail.example.com>
Aug  9 10:53:49 mail postfix/proxymap[304446]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf is unavailable. open /etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf: Permission denied
Aug  9 10:53:49 mail postfix/cleanup[306428]: warning: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf lookup error for "example@example.com"
Aug  9 10:53:49 mail postfix/cleanup[306428]: warning: 36D3B123381: virtual_alias_maps map lookup problem for example@example.com -- message not accepted, try again later
```

Here is the output of:

```
namei -l /etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf

f: /etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root etc
drwxr-xr-x root root postfix
drwxr-xr-x root root sql
-rw-r-x--- root root mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
```

What exactly might be the problem here? How can I debug and then fix this?

Comment: The problem might be missing permissions. Please show the output of `namei -l /etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf`

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, Added the output as requested.

Answer (score 2):

As expected, your postfix user has no permissions to read the configuration files.

```
sudo chmod o+r /etc/postfix/sql/*
```

Or, if you don't want other users to read the files

```
sudo chown :postfix /etc/postfix/sql/*
```

---

Side note: You don't really need the executable bit for the group here:

```
sudo chmod g-x /etc/postfix/sql/*
```

Comment: I tried "sudo chown :postfix /etc/postfix/sql/*" but am still getting "warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf is unavailable. open /etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf: Permission denied" in my logs.

Comment: What program does the warning come from? Is it running under the user `postfix`?

Comment: Nevermind. I think it might have taken some time for the permissions to change, or, I misread the new logs and timestamps. Everything is working fine now. I will upvote this and mark it as solved.